# Fetch/checkout failed with visual studio 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

Recently I changed my password for TFS service and started facing below issue

Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.
Authentication failed for 'http://Path'.

[image]
 - **Worked fine with Visual Studio 2019** but failed with Visual Studio 2017

Things I tried to resolve this issue:
 - Updated password in Credential Manager
 - Clearing visual studio cache

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Instead of update password in Credential Manager try to remove it. When connect git in VS2017, you should be able to enter it again.  More ways for troubleshooting, pleas take a look at weiwei's answer in this similar question [Git failed with a fatal error.Authentication failed when clone repository from VS 2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/304224/git-failed-with-a-fatal-errorauthentication-failed.html)

Besides, as a workaround, you could also try to use  Personal Access Token and use that to connect directly. For details please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56028075/5391065

---

According to your description and situation, since it worked fine with VS2019 and not work with VS2017, this maybe with some Credential cache.

Make sure you have clean clear for the cache with Visual Studio 2017.

Besides, you could also try to run Visual Studio under sign-in credentials that are different from your signed-in Windows account, open the context menu for `devenv.exe` to access your **run as** options. If you don't see the run as option as shown in the following example, you may need to press SHIFT before right-clicking to see the run as options.

[image]

You can locate the executable in the following folder: `*Drive*:\\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.0\Common7\IDE\`

Which may do the trick.

Comment: @Raka Whats the detail error did you get? Could you add the error or screenshot when you use VS2017. Besides, have you tried with VS2017 on another machine, this will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Raka Instead of update password in Credential Manager try to remove it. When connect git in VS2017, you should be able to enter it again.  Besides, as a workaround, you could also try to use  Personal Access Token and use that to connect directly. For details please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56028075/5391065

Comment: sorry for late reply. Removing password in Credential manager helped.

Answer (score 0):

Close all Visual Studio instances.

Delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`.

If the issue still persist, call `devenv /resetuserdata` to clear user's data.